# "lang.link.toolbar is null or not an object" when using CKeditor with IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I get this error only in IE7.

> lang.link.toolbar is null or not an object

I thought I may have accidentally deleted something when setting up the language, so I went to `ckeditor/lang/en.js` and there was indeed a `CKEDITOR.lang.en.link.toolbar` being set.

I set up the actual CKEditor using the jQuery adapter like so...

```
$( '#input-product-description' ).ckeditor(
  function() { /* callback code */ },
  {
  startupFocus: true,
  language: 'en',
  defaultLanguage: 'en',
  removePlugins : 'smiley, about, sourcearea, flash, newpage, pagebreak, popup, preview, stylescombo, table, tabletools, elementspath, save, templates, print, find, font, forms, horizontalrule, justify, format, colorbutton, div, blockquote, indent, clipboard, image, showblocks, wsc' ,
  toolbar :
      [
        ['Undo','Redo'],
        ['Bold','Italic'],
        ['NumberedList','BulletedList']
      ],
   resize_enabled: false   

 });
```

Does anyone know why this error may occur?

Comment: Possibly related: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7705

Comment: Just a throwaway shot-in-the-dark suggestion, but I remember running into some problems with IE7 with ready vs. load. Maybe ensure the binding occurs after a window.load event.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the ckEditor language plz try to add this as the following:
or you can see the following examble from the Multi-language interface tab on [CKEditor language demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo)

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editorName; // GETTING AN INSTANCE OF THE EDITOR
var editorData = editor ? editor.getData() : initialHtml; // GET THE OLD DATA IF YOU WANT TO REUSE IT
if (editor) {
editor.destroy(); // DESTROY THE OLD EDITOR
}
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('demoInside', { language: 'en' }); // add new one to your target
editor.setData(editorData); // set your new data
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you make your call once the editor is ready.

[InstanceReady event](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#event%3ainstanceReady)